# ModuleNotFoundError partway through running module

Tags: python, python-import

I'm running a file in Python using `python -m <filename>`. But during--not before!--the script's execution, I get the following exception:

```
<Path to Python>: Error while finding module specification for 'gentests.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'gentests' while trying to find 'gentests.py'). Try using 'gentests' instead of 'gentests.py' as the module name.
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: read the error carefully every time you get it because it's provided to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **'gentests'** instead of **'gentests.py'** as the module name.

Comment: I had already tried that, but it worked this time, oddly. Perhaps the change had to do with the `git clean -fdx` I ran as a second attempt at a solution.